# Insert new records across Cascaded tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

[image]

Objective: New Data To be inserted across the 3 cascaded tablesWhere OwnershipID, RollID, PeopleID are auto incremental(seeding ids)..

```
RollNumber             FullName

444201000703904        HALL SANDRA THELMA    
444201000703905        GOLDING RONALD JESSE  
444201000703908        CLAYTON JOHN WESLEY  
444201001704556        MARS LTD         
444201001704558        ONTARIO LTD          
444201001704560        DECARLE DAVE
```

HOPING A HELPING HAND HERE HOW TO CREATE SQL SCRIPT BUT FIRST TIMER....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @roll_id int, @people_id  
insert into people (fullname) values ('HALL SANDRA THELMA');
set @people_id select SCOPE_IDENTITY();
insert into roll (rollnumber) values ('444201000703904');
set @roll_id select SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 
insert into ownership (roll_id, people_id) values (@roll_id, @people_id);
```

Comment: is this can be used in bulk uploading?

Comment: There is nothing in the question about bulk uploading.  You asked for a script and you got one.

Comment: is there a difference if its a bulk uploading?